# Using a Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures

I want use a stored procedure in my project but I have no idea about it. Please could you tell me a little bit about how to use I can use one in my vb.net application ?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a stored-procedure as simply a function for a database that you can execute.  See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

Answer (score -1):

I think you can visit it http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx to have a look at it.